# MessageBox on Mouse Hover event of Textbox implementing MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am new to MVVM in Silverlight.

How can I show a textbox on mouse hover event of the textbox while implementing MVVM. Since there is no command property attached to which I can bind to some action as there is in Button control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interactions to make commands execute on any kind of event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseHover">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowTextBoxCommand}">
     </i:InvokeCommandAction>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

but first you need to declare the name space in your UserControl like so:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and you need to have expression blend sdk installed and the assemblies referenced in your project.

Here is a good article that helped me get started on using MVVM with events on the UI side:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204567/Using-Microsoft-Expression-Blend-4-0-to-Implement